# How to maintain as single set of properties/form field keys in angular application?

Tags: angular, enums, angular-reactive-forms

So I'm working on an Angular application where the user will create a profile across multiple views. The user will be creating only one profile per session and will input the data through reactive form fields.

I am thinking about an injectable service that keeps track of the current status of the profile. And then in each view there is a formGroup and on every `onSubmit` the profile information is transfered from the formGroup to the unique session instance maintained by the service.

I will have to repeat the name of the profile fields in the model, the Profile class, and in the different form groups for every view. So there will have to be a `name` in the model Profile class and one in the FormGroup of the View where the name is entered. I don't want to enter a hardcoded string every time I want to write to a field or create a FormControl for it. I thought about creating an enum in an external file and import it in both the model class and the components of the different views. So:

```
export enum ProfileFieldsEnum {
    NAME = 'name',
    EMAIL = 'email'
}
```

would then be used like:

```
import { ProfileFieldsEnum } from './profile-fields-keys';

export class Profile {

    private profileFieldsKeys = Object.keys(ProfileFieldsEnum).filter(k => typeof ProfileFieldsEnum[k as any] === 'number');
    private profileFieldsValues = new Set(this.profileFieldsKeys.map(k => ProfileFieldsEnum[k as any]));

    constructor() {}

    setProperty(key: string, value: any) {
        if (this.profileFieldsValues.has(key)) {
            this[key] = value;
        }
    }

    getProperty(key: string): any {
        return this.profileFieldsValues[key];
    }
}
```

In the model class and like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoggerService } from 'src/app/services/logger.service';
import { Profile } from 'src/app/model/profile';
import { ProfileFieldsEnum } from 'src/app/model/profile-fields-keys';    

@Component({
  selector: 'profile-search',
  templateUrl: './profile-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-name.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileNameComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private logger: LoggerService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileParentForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required]    // Here I'd like to use ProfileFieldsEnum.NAME instead of 'name'
    });

    this.profileParentForm.valueChanges.subscribe(form => 
    this.logger.log(form));
  }
}
```

I still haven't written the `onSubmit` code.

So I guess I am not the first one to run into this situation. What have you guys done? What would you do? Feel free to comment on any of my ideas, I feel I got a bit bogged down in the details and missed some of the big picture. There must be an easier/simpler way to do this.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, If I conclude your question, you need to create a profile FormGroup without writing the same code in multiple components?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code can be simplified as -

#### Profile

Lets refactor your profile class. As of now it does addition process to keep the record for keys and values separately but it could be changed as -

```
import { ProfileFieldsEnum } from './profile-fields-keys';

export class Profile {

    private profile = {}; // it will add the property and value dynamically

    constructor() {}

    setProperty(key: string, value: any) {
       this.profile[key] = value; //set the property value, create new one if doesn't exist
    }

    getProperty(key: string): any {
        return this.profile[key];
    }
}
```

#### ProfileNameComponent

If don't want to hard code the property name then yes you can use enumeration to achieve this.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileParentForm = this.fb.group({
       [ProfileFieldsEnum.NAME]: ['', Validators.required] //<-- enum is used for control name
    });

    this.profileParentForm.valueChanges.subscribe(form => 
    this.logger.log(form));
  }
```